# Who is Quthubuzzaman?

Tags: dawah, sufism

I’m hearing a lot of Quthubuzzaman these days.
Can anyone please tell me what his speciality is?

I also heard people like Imam Shafi (r.a), Muhiyudheen Sheikh (r.a), etc were Quthubuzzamans of their time...

Can anyone please explain clearly?

Comment: Different sufi groups and sects may identify different individuals as "the pole of the era". Shias consider Hujjat ibn al-Hassan, al-Mahdi to be the "owner of the era and the time" and "Allah's Proof (Hujjat) on Earth": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_al-Mahdi

Comment: But Mahdi hasn't come ryt?
I think this person will be there in every era....common for everyone, like the imam Mahdi (r.a) who is going to come.

Comment: Did you read the wiki article? Mahdi according to 12er Shias was born 12 centuries ago and has lived all these centuries to date. He is among us but in occultation! He aids and guides his followers and can be contacted by the most pious and enlightened scholars and believers.

Answer (score -2):

Quthubuzzaman is the superiormost and the leader of all awlias of a time.. Its true that in many Sufi orders, the mureeds may claim their shaik to be Quthubuzzaman seeing the degree of themselves getting heightened by the shaik. And to a mureed his shaik should be superiormost to him... So i don't know whether that practice is wrong or not. Anyway Quthubuzzaman will exist in all eras, and then particularly its not Mahdi AS right now. Its true that many renowned Sunni scholars like Imam Bukhari R.A told Mahdi AS is already born. But Quthubul Aqthab Shaik Muhyuddeen Abdul Qadir jeelani R.A should also be then living at Mahdi ASs period but he was the Quthubuzzaman. That goes for many shaiks. Still to find the real Quthubuzzaman we cant listen to what mureeds say, coz they can exaggerate. But if a shaik proclaims himself as the quthub of the era, then we can agree he has greater chance of being the Quthubuzzaman. Coz the previous self proclaimed Quthubuzzamans did the same.

Comment: I have done baiath under the order of Quthubuzzaman Shaik Yousuf Sulthan Shah Qadiri. And unlike how some orders nowadays exaggerates their  shaik to be Quthubuzzaman, my shaik have proclaimed himself to be the Quthubuzzaman and any wali doubtful can appear before him to check and he has the authority to remove wilayath of anybody who doesn't accept him

Comment: Did you mean to say "And **like** how some ..."